# Closing off a thread (and cleaning up memory) which is waiting for mp.pool.map to return values

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have an embarrassingly parallel problem which I aim to solve using the multiprocessing library. I want to add functionality by having a GUI and a cancel button. I am using pool.map to spawn my processes and pool.terminate() to close off all my worker processes. However, I assume that pool.map is blocking and waiting for the results to return. I am also using threading to ensure the GUI (Tkinter) doesn't freeze.

Some code so you know what I mean.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading
import Tkinter

def expensiveFunction()
    #do some stuff


if __name__=='main':
    master=Tkinter.Tk()
    master.title("My Title")
    master.geometry("some dimension")
    master.resizable(0,0)

    def analysisFunction():
        global pool
        #do some preprocessing stuff
        Input=[,,,] #some iterable here
        pool=multiprocessing.Pool()
        Results=pool.map(expensiveFunction,Input)

    def threadedFunction():
        myThread=threading.Thread(None,analysisFunction,None)

    def cancel():
        global pool
        pool.terminate()

    runButton=Tkinter.Button(master,text = "Run Analysis",command = threadedFunction)
    runButton.pack(fill = x)
    cancelButton=Tkinter.Button(master,text = "Cancel Analysis", command = cancel)
    cancelButton.pack(fill = x)
```

Basically when u launch the script, it opens a GUI, and if u press run it runs, if i press cancel I can see that the processes are killed but im assuming myThread is waiting for the pool.map to return values. The issue is if I run, then cancel, the memory of my master process just keeps increasing because the thread is just waiting there stuck.

Is there any possible way to somehow kill the thread / remove the memory. I need the thread there so that I can access my GUI while the analysis is being performed to cancel it.

Cheers guys

Edit: To summarise my issue, everytime i press the runButton a thread is spawned which does some preprocessing stuff, it keeps all this stuff in memory, then it spawns pool processes which i can abruptly cancel using the pool.terminate(), however when i do the thread isnt closed off and all the memory is kept. killing my RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pool.map_async`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async

You can supply a callback so that you can perform some action in your Tk GUI after it has completed.

This is what it would roughly look like:

```
def analysisFunction():
    global pool
    #do some preprocessing stuff
    Input=[,,,] #some iterable here
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map_async(expensiveFunction,Input, callback=success)

def threadedFunction(success_callback):
    myThread=threading.Thread(target=analysisFunction)

def success(results):
    # Do stuff with the results
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply mate, being able to access the GUI is not the issue. The issue is when I cancel the analysis by terminating the pool. The thread "myThread" continues to run and the memory isnt cleaned up. If i run an analysis myThread is putting some stuff in memory (preprocessing) before it spawns off the pool. If i abruptly interrupt the pools, the memory from the thread remains, and it uses up my RAM. Hope that clears up my problem. Thanks for your reply anyway mate.

Comment: Oh I get what your saying. Because its mapped in aysnc fashion, the thread will just exit as soon as the workers processes are spawned regardless of whether i terminate or not. I will try this tomorrow morning. THANKS HEAPS MATE